# CNN batch with images of different size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I restored a pre-trained model for face detection which takes a single image at a time and returns bounding boxes. How can I make it take a batch of images if these images have different sizes?

Comment: Are you restoring pre-trained model for training?or inference?

Comment: @naman for inference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.image.resize_images`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images) method to achieve this. According to [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images) `tf.image.resize_images`:

> Resize images to size using the specified method.
>
> Resized images will be distorted if their original aspect ratio is not
>   the same as size. To avoid distortions see
>   `tf.image.resize_image_with_pad`.

*How to use it?*

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model

x = Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name='image_input')
resize_x = tf.image.resize_images(x, [32,32])
vgg_model = load_vgg()(resize_x)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=vgg_model.output)
model.compile(...)
model.predict(...)
```